# Creating an int array filed with zeros in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a 10 dimensional array that's filled with zeros.
If I simply use `int[] array = new int[10];` do I have a guarantee that all int's in the array are zeros?

Comment: A 10 dimensional array : `int[][][][][][][][][][] array;` is not the same thing as a 1 dimensional array with 10 elements : `new int[10]`.

Comment: In his defense you could represent a 10 dimensional vector with 10 elements. Granted the terminology is off but the spirit of the question is clear.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

int always has initial value of 0. so

```
new int[10]
```

is enough.

for other values use `Arrays` utility class.

```
   int arrayDefaultedToTen[] = new int[100]; 

   Arrays.fill(arrayDefaultedToTen, 10);
```

this method fills the array (first arg) with 10 (second arg).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's only one-dimensional, not ten.

Comment: And a ten-dimensional array of size 10 in all dimensions would require 37GB of memory, if I calculated correctly.

Comment: I calculate 10^9 * (8 (reference to) + 16 (array header) + 10*4) which is ~ 60 GB. ;)

Comment: Orrrrr... it's a ten-dimensional array that can hold 32 enumerable states :)

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `new int[10]` will be plenty. Refer to [the authority for the default values](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: The REAL authority is JLS 15.10.1 (paragraph 5).

Comment: I looked but couldn't find a link very quickly and figured Oracle was enough of an authority; thanks for the spec though